# python replace word not substring

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace, python-re

I want to replace a word by another in a column of a dataframe. Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
text="age engage"
df=pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in text.split('\n')])
df['text'] = df[0].str.replace(r"age","âge")
```

The codes that I found on stackoverflow (and this one included) permit me to obtain `df['text']="âge engâge"`, when I want to obtain `df['text']="âge engage"`. Could anyone help me improve my code? I have dozens of different words that I want to replace in my dataframe, so I would like to use a simple code to implement to different words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try-

```
import pandas as pd
text="age engage"
df=pd.DataFrame([x.split(';') for x in text.split('\n')])
df['text'] = df[0].str.replace(r"^age","âge") # the carrot indicates to only match from the start of the line
```

Result

```
        0        text
0  age engage  âge engage
```

You can also look in regex, a good site to play around when it comes to pattern matching [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: It works perfect and so simple! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MGFern If my answer may have helped you, feel free to mark this as accepted by clicking the checkmark (✔️), also feel free to upvote with the triangle pointing up. Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information about accepting and upvoting answers.

Comment: I apologize for questioning this only now, but I figured out this problem only today. This code only works for the first word that I replace, for the 2nd word that I try to replace (e.g. "makes" to "make") no change happens. I would like to replace several different words

Comment: look into **re.sub** for regex. playground [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a method like that:

```
import re

text = 'age engage'
for words in ['age']:
    if re.search(r'\b' + words + r'\b', text):
        print('{0}'.format(words).replace(r"age","âge"))
```

output:

```
âge
```